# Proof that a quotient map has trivial image

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis

Given a normed vector space $(V, ||\quad||)$ over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, let $B$ be the closed unit ball in it centered at $0$ and $W$ be the subspace of $V$ spanned by a finite subset $F$ of $B$. If we know the canonical quotient map $q: V \to V/W$ satisfies $q(B) = q(V)$, then I need to show that $q(V)$ only contains a trivial element, which implies $W = V$. I do not know how to do this and hope to get some help here.

For the context, I am reading a proof in my lecture notes for the statement "a normed vector space $(V, ||\quad||)$ over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ has finite dimension if and only if the closed unit ball in it is compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\|\overline{u}\|_{V/W} := \inf_{w \in W} \|u - w\|_V$ be the usual norm on $V/W$ (if you haven't heard of it, you should check as an exercise that it is a seminorm for a generic subspace $W$, and that it is a norm when $W$ is closed, which is the case here).
For all $u \in V$, you can deduce from $q(B) = q(V)$ that there exists $v \in B$ such that $\overline{u} = \overline{v}$, thus
$$\|\overline{u}\|_{V/W} = \|\overline{v}\|_{V/W} \leq \|v\|_V \leq 1$$
However, this is absurd if $V/W \neq \left\{\overline{0}\right\}$ since $V/W$ would contain at least one vector of norm, say, $2$, hence $V/W = \left\{\overline{0}\right\}$, which indeed provides $V = W$.

Notice that we haven't used the fact that $W$ is finite-dimensional, only that it is closed. If $W$ is not closed, what you would deduce is that $V/W$ is equal to its set of $0$-seminormed vectors, which means that $V = \overline{W}$ instead (should be a part of the first exercise).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  For the existence of a vector of norm 2 part, I guess we need a (trivial) assumption that $V$ is not trivial. If $V$ is trivial, then the closed unit ball of it will be obviously compact.

Comment: @zlbi The quotient containing a vector of quotient norm $2$ only requires the quotient to be non-trivial, so technically I did cover that case, but yes I didn't have trivial $V$ in mind at the time of writing, good call.